No solitaire in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
There is no solitaire in Ubuntu 24.04.
How to install solitaire like previous versions of Ubuntu?

The preinstalled games were removed in Ubuntu 24.04.
You can easily install them with the command
sudo apt install gnome-games

For more information about the history of games in ubuntu and the decision that led to their removal from Ubuntu 24.04, read this OMG Ubuntu post.
